# facebook, customized post on wall from Graph API

Tags: android, facebook

I want to send posts from Android to Facebook wall. Some initial code works but in my post occurs following problems:

1. If I set "link" in post then on top of post appears description a la
   "JohnDoe published link from application SomeApp".
   I want to have in top only standard user name a la "John Doe".
2. If I set picture in post then link to picture becomes link where user lands after clicking on post.
   I want to show picture from eg. "mysite.com/picture.png" but after click on post I want to take user to "www.myadres.com".

I am trying to find solution basing on Graph API [as REST API is now deprecated].

Snippet of current code making above behaviour.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "test message");
params.putString("link", "http://www.google.no");
params.putString("caption", "app caption");
params.putString("description", "this app is about ...");
params.putString("picture", "http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/img/facebook_icon_large.png");
params.putString("name", " just won 1M500");

Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new BaseRequestListener() {
  @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
    System.out.println("response = " + response);
  }
}, null);
```

Thank you in advance for help!
Best Regards
GT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make post that looks like "normal user post "[and not like "sharing links"] post it with action `"feed"` and NOT `"me/feed"`.

Finally:

```
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("feed", params, "POST", new BaseRequestListener() {
  @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
    System.out.println("response = " + response);
  }
}, null);
```